# Update Column based on row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, row-number

I created a column with default value 0 for my table. I want to update that table with the correct sequence number. Could I do that with Row_Number?

my table is:

```
PersonID |  Code  |  Sequence Number
---------+--------+------------
10       | D112  |    0
10       | D112  |    0
10       | D112  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
10       | D112  |    0
10       | D112  |    0
10       | D112  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
10       | E110  |    0
```

i want my table to be like this:

```
PersonID |  Code  |  Sequence Number
---------+--------+------------
10       | D112  |    1
10       | D112  |    1
10       | D112  |    1
10       | E110  |    2
10       | E110  |    2
10       | E110  |    2
11       | M490  |    1
11       | M490  |    1
11       | M490  |    1
11       | N550  |    2
11       | N550  |    2
11       | N550  |    2
```

This is the code that I have but not sure if this is correct.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    t.Sequence Number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonID, t.Code ORDER BY t.PersonID) AS RN
FROM Table AS t )

UPDATE CTE 
SET Sequence Number = RN
```

Comment: Looks the select statement is correct

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (PersonId INt, Code CHAR(4), SequenceNumber INT)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (10,'D112',0),(10,'D112',0),(10,'D112',0),(10,'E110',0)
,(10,'E110',0),(10,'E110',0),(10,'D112',0),(10,'D112',0),(10,'D112',0),(10,'E110',0)
,(10,'E110',0),(10,'E110',0)


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    PersonId
    ,Code
    ,SequenceNumber
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonID ORDER BY t.Code ) AS RN
FROM
    @Table AS t)


UPDATE cte
    SET SequenceNumber = RN

SELECT *
FROm
    @Table
```

You are very close just need to do your `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` slightly different and then use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` to handle the ties.